# Drools Integration With Spring Mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration, drools, kie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring 
          http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd">

    <kie:kmodule id="kmodule1">
         <kie:kbase name="rules" packages="com.spring.drool.rules">
              <kie:ksession name="ksession-rules" type="stateless" />
         </kie:kbase>
    </kie:kmodule>

    <beans:bean id="kiePostProcessor" 
           class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor">
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

I am trying to integrate drools with spring mvc i am getting some errors in servlet-context.xml

Error 1: At `http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd`

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document `http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring.xsd`, because

1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 
3) the root element of the document is not